# Test connection to SQL Server with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Before the `EntityFramework` creates databases with `Code First` manner, I need to verify the `Data Source`, `UserId` and `Password`. At that moment, no data could be read for testing connection. My goal is to configure the connectionString for the product, and modify the `web.config` for users. So I need a method to verify if the configuration is valid or not. Especially the accuracy of `Data Source`, `UserId` and `Password`.

So, I hope to test connection of a SQL Server, and the SQL Server might not have any databases at all. I need to test the connection ability, about the `Data Source`, `UserId` and `Password`. If some parameters are invalid, it should show error messages to the user.

So, I need following features.

1. The `Data Source`, `UserId`, and `Password` are decided by user input.
2. No extra database is created. If any database for testing is created, it should be deleted at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The sample models

I wrote a simple `Database model` with EntityFramework, create it **for testing**, and delete the database at the end. The connectionString is composed by program, so the `TestDbContext` should accept the `DbConnection` parameter.

```
public class Test
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Field { get; set; }
}
public class TestDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Test> TestSet { get; set; }

    public TestDbContext() {}
    /// For self-composed connection string.
    public TestDbContext(DbConnection conn) : base(conn, true) {}
}
```

### Compose connection string

Then, the `connectionString` could be composed by `SqlConnectionStringBuilder`, which is for `System.Data.SqlClient` data provider. And the `SqlConnection` is the sub-class of `DbConnection`, it accepts the string generated by `sb`.

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder sb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
sb.DataSource = ...; //< The `Data Source` parameter
// The `InitialCatalog` parameter.
// Create an unique database for testing. And avoid name confliction.
sb.InitialCatalog = "testing" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"); 
sb.UserID = ...; //< The `UserId`
sb.Password = ...; //< The `Password` of `UserId`.
sb.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;

SqlConnection dbConn = new SqlConnection(sb.ToString());

// dbConn.Open(); 
// It will be failed when the database had not been created.
// But, I need to verify the db server, account and password, 
// no matter whether the database is created or not.
```

### Testing connection

Then, test connection by `EntityFramework`. It is very convenient.

```
// Test by self-composed connection string.
using (TestDbContext db = new TestDbContext(dbConn))
{
    // Create database. 
    // If failed to connect to the database server, it will throw an exception.
    db.Database.CreateIfNotExists();

    // Insert an item.
    var item = new Test() { Field="Hello World!!"};
    db.TestSet.Add(item);
    db.SaveChanges();

    // Delete database after testing
    db.Database.Delete();
}
```

Comment: It is **exceptionally** rare that you would want "test a connection" code to create or destroy a database, or even insert data (unless it is inside a transaction that you are going to roll back) - the above example is pretty dangerous, IMO. Frankly, most commonly you'd simply read (select) the top 1 anything from some table. The start of the answer (`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`, etc) is great, though

Comment: agree with Marc, most sql heartbeat are base on a `select @@version`.

Comment: The `code first` will create database. But I need a method to test the accuracy of `UserId`, `Password` and `Data Source`. The `TestDbContext` is only for **testing**, it's not used on the real application. The databases, which are really needed for application, may be not created at all, so there might be no data for reading or testing.